# Can you Group XArray Data Array by Day of Month?

Tags: python, datetime, python-xarray

If there was a variable in an xarray dataset with a time dimension with daily values over some multiyear time span

2017-01-01 ... 2018-12-31, then it is possible to group the data by month, or by the day of the year, using

`.groupby("time.month") or .groupby("time.dayofyear")`

Is there a way to efficiently group the data by the day of the month, for example if I wanted to calculate the mean value on the 21st of each month?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the xarray docs on the [`DateTimeAccessor`](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.core.accessor_dt.DatetimeAccessor.html) helper object. For more info, you can also check out the xarray docs on [Working with Time Series Data: Datetime Components](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/user-guide/time-series.html#datetime-components), which in turn refers to the pandas docs on [date/time components](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html).

You're looking for `day`. Unfortunately, both pandas and xarray simply describe `.dt.day` as referring to "the days of the datetime" which isn't particularly helpful. But if you take a look at python's native [`datetime.Date.day`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.day) definition, you'll see the more specific:

> **`date.day`**
> Between 1 and the number of days in the given month of the given year.

So, simply

```py
da.groupby("time.day")
```

Should do the trick!

Comment: Oh goodness, lovely to know. Thanks Michael!

Answer (score -1):

I not sure, but maybe you can do like this:

```
import datetime

x = datetime.datetime.now()

day = x.strftime("%d")
month = x.strftime("%m")
year = x.strftime("%Y")

.groupby(month) or .groupby(year)
```

Comment: Hi Matin - welcome to stack overflow, and thanks for taking the time to add an answer! Unfortunately, your answer does not address the question, which is asking specifically about the python package xarray and ways to resample data to a daily frequency. Passing a single day into .groupby won't work. If you're interested in contributing more answers (please do!) then check out the guides to [answer] and [What are tags and how should I use them?](/help/tagging) and you'll be a pro in no time. Thanks!

Comment: thank you bro @MichaelDelgado for your guide, I just send this answer, and maybe that is correct for questioner, Thanks again